# How does this array print this barchart?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class BarChart // Modified from Fig 7.6
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] grades = {90, 71, 89, 75, 83, 87, 81, 100, 99, 83,
                65, 100, 91, 78, 88, 62, 55, 84, 73, 89}; // 20 elements
        int[] frequency = new int[11]; // 11 ranges 
        System.out.println("Grade distribution:");
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            frequency[grades[i]/10]++; //How does this work? why does it say 10
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 10) {
                System.out.printf("%5d: ", 100);
            }
            else {
                System.out.printf("%02d-%02d: ", i * 10, i * 10 + 9);
            }
            for (int stars = 0; stars < frequency[i]; stars++) { // How does it know where to print the stars?
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: pic of output]

I am having trouble understanding how this program works. I put in some questions as comments to get a clearer answer. I attached a pic of the output as well.

Comment: `grades[i]/10` divides the grades by 10. And please reindent your code

Comment: ...and the `printf` statement conditionally prints a certain number of stars.  If you have access to a debugger, I would recommend that you step through this code to see how it works.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but StackOverflow is not a platform to explain others code. Minor comment: use **code indentation** to convey program structure

Comment: Why would I want to divide the grade by 10?

Comment: @K.A. Everything is answered in the answer!!! -> it is to translate your grade in the frequency array in the corresponding [0]...[10] cell that will be used after to print the number of stars to show the distribution!!

Comment: Thanks @Allan, appreciate your time and everyone else's.

Answer (score 2):

I have commented in the code directly:

```
public class BarChart // Modified from Fig 7.6
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /*array that contains the data that will be used to display the distribution*/
        int[] grades = {90, 71, 89, 75, 83, 87, 81, 100, 99, 83,
            65, 100, 91, 78, 88, 62, 55, 84, 73, 89}; // 20 elements
        /*this frequecncy is used to divided your interval [0,100] in 11 slices*/
        int[] frequency = new int[11]; // 11 ranges 
        System.out.println("Grade distribution:");
        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            /*division of your i element of grade array by 10, 
            10 here is used here to make correspond your grades 
            to your slices defined in the frequency variable, 
            (type int divided by 10 will give an int as output 
            (the decimals are truncated -> equivalent as taking the floor of the number) 
            so you have an int that can be used as an index for your frequency array, 
            the grades[i]/10 will be incremented by 1 -> this will allow to print the stars after*/
            frequency[grades[i]/10]++; 
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++) //loop that will do the display
        {
            if (i == 10) {
                System.out.printf("%5d: ", 100);//this will print the last line of your output, 
                //printf will not print the EOL char so the other printing operations are done on the same line
            }
            else {
                System.out.printf("%02d-%02d: ", i * 10, i * 10 + 9); 
                //this is will create your DD-DD intervals (00-09:, 10-19)
            }
            for (int stars = 0; stars < frequency[i]; stars++) { 
            // the value stored in frequency thanks to this operation: frequency[grades[i]/10]++; will be displayed,
            //you loop from 0 until you reach the value of frequency[i] and display a star at each loop
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();//this will print the end of line character
        }
    }
}
```